# Get a folder name from a path

Tags: c#

I have some path  `c:\server\folderName1\another name\something\another folder\` .

How i can extract from there the last folder name ?

I have tried several things but they didn't work.

I just don't want to search for the last `\` and then to take the rest .

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
string a = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\server\folderName1\another name\something\another folder\").Name;
```

Comment: Real shame this isn't more obviously described in the Intellisense hint! :)

Answer (score 5):

[`DirectoryInfo.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name(v=VS.90).aspx) works:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\users\\jon\\test\\");
        Console.WriteLine(info.Name); // Prints test
    }                                                
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out `DirectoryInfo.Name`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Also possible using System.IO.Path:

```
string s = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\server\folderName1\another name\something\another folder\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one line System.Linq command:

```
foldername.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Reverse().ToArray()[0]
```