# Get the (last part of) current directory name in C#

Tags: c#, string, filepath

I need to get the last part of current directory, for example  from `/Users/smcho/filegen_from_directory/AIRPassthrough`, I need to get `AIRPassthrough`.

With python, I can get it with this code.

```
import os.path

path = "/Users/smcho/filegen_from_directory/AIRPassthrough"
print os.path.split(path)[-1]
```

Or

```
print os.path.basename(path)
```

How can I do the same thing with C#?

### ADDED

With the help from the answerers, I found what I needed.

```
using System.Linq;
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fullPath).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string projectName  = fullPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
```

or

```
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fullPath).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string projectName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
```

Comment: Several possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471310/c-how-to-grep-the-last-word-from-a-directory-path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407905/get-a-folder-name-from-a-path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670819/get-directory-from-full-path

Comment: In python, you should rather do `os.path.basename(path)`.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You're looking for [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).
Note that this won't work if the path ends in a `\`.

Comment: @anti: Wrong; I tried it.  Strings are strings.  Paste `Path.GetFileName("/Users/smcho/filegen_from_directory/AIRPassthrough")` into LINQPad if you don't believe me.

Comment: @antisanity No, it will return the directory name, but it probably is not exactly what the question was about.

Comment: @Jakob: Given the title, I think this is what the question is about.

Comment: I think maybe it dont work because windows directory seperator is \ not /

Comment: @Light: It **does** work; try it.  The `Path` class handles both separators.

Comment: To have this work with a directory retrieved by Directory.GetDirectories use:

string directoryName =  Path.GetFileName(directory.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));

Comment: What if you want a directory and not a file name?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: It makes no difference; this just manipulates strings.

Answer (score 278):

You could try:

```
var path = @"/Users/smcho/filegen_from_directory/AIRPassthrough/";
var dirName = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
```

Comment: I like this better than the chosen answer. (Ab)using GetFileName is semantically wrong since it's a directory you're trying to retrieve. Also, to make GetFileName deterministic means you have to account for the possibility of a trailing forward slash or backslash, and trim it off, which is ugly.

Comment: var dirName = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathWithFilename)).Name //is better

Comment: @kernowcode I believe that would return "filegen_from_directory" instead of ''AIRPassthrough" as requested by the OP.

Comment: @SimonBrangwin I thought everything is a file in Linux :)

Answer (score 23):

This is a slightly different answer, depending on what you have. If you have a list of files and need to get the name of the last directory that the file is in you can do this:

```
string path = "/attachments/1828_clientid/2938_parentid/somefiles.docx";
string result = new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.Name;
```

This will return "2938_parentid"

Answer (score 12):

Well, to *exactly* answer your question title :-)

```
var lastPartOfCurrentDirectoryName = 
   Path.GetFileName(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

Answer (score 10):

rather then using the '/' for the call to split, better to use the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` :

like so:

```
path.split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last()
```

Comment: One thing I don't like about using this solution is that it makes an assumption as to where the string is coming from.  What if they're reading *nix logs on a Windows System?  Then the wrong character will be utilized and you'll end up with the entire path, rather than the intended effect.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: i agree with you on this. the OP said 'last part of current directory' so for that, this is fine.

Comment: @BobG So from your point of view, what is better solution?

Answer (score 7):

```
var lastFolderName = Path.GetFileName(
    path.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar));
```

This works if the path happens to contain forward slash separators or backslash separators.

Comment: The applied location of .TrimEnd() is incorrect.  It should be applied to **path**, not **Path.GetFileName**.  See the answer from @Fatlad

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String newString = "";
String oldString = "/Users/smcho/filegen_from_directory/AIRPassthrough";

int indexOfLastSlash = oldString.LastIndexOf('/');

newString = oldString.Substring(indexOfLastSlash, oldString.Length);
```

Code may be off (I haven't tested it) but the idea should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Uri class.

```
new Uri("file:///Users/smcho/filegen_from_directory/AIRPassthrough").Segments.Last()
```

You may prefer to use this class if you want to get some other segment, or if you want to do the same thing with a web address.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine with me :)

```
Path.GetFileName(path.TrimEnd('\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :

`Path.GetFileName(userpath)`