# How can I get the last folder from a path string?

Tags: c#, parsing, filepath

I have a directory that looks something like this:

```
C:\Users\me\Projects\
```

In my application, I append to that path a given project name:

```
C:\Users\me\Projects\myProject
```

After, I want to be able to pass that into a method. Inside this method I would also like to use the project name. What is the best way to parse the path string to get the last folder name?

I know a work-around would be to pass the path and the project name into the function, but I was hoping I could limit it to one parameter.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Barely. I've searched around and found some similar questions but couldn't find one that did what I needed. My best assumption is that the `Path` class has a method for this, but I don't know what.

Comment: Using one parameter only is not necessarily the better solution.

Comment: What is your workaround?

Comment: My answer uses the Path Method @McAdam331

Comment: You can check similar question in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018293/get-the-last-part-of-current-directory-name-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ThomasW. I think my work around would have been to just pass in two parameters, if I couldn't find a quick and nice way to get the last folder.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can do:

```
string dirName = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\me\Projects\myProject\").Name;
```

Or use `Path.GetFileName` like *(with a bit of hack)*:

```
string dirName2 = Path.GetFileName(
              @"C:\Users\me\Projects\myProject".TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
```

[`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the file name from the path, if the path is terminating with `\` then it would return an empty string, that is why I have used `TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)`

Comment: DirectoryInfo method worked. I would think that's the preferred method? Thanks!

Comment: Both of them should work, but IMO, yes `DirectoryInfo` is more clean and convey the intent more clearly.

Comment: I like `DirectoryInfo` because I see that it works regardless of whether or not it is terminated with a `\\`. It shouldn't be, in my application, but I tested it both ways just in case. It looks cleaner, too.

Comment: And, I should add that yes both worked, but I think I will use the first.

Answer (score 3):

```
string path = @"C:\Users\me\Projects\myProject";
string result = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
```

result = myProject

Comment: This will not work if the path ends with a back slash like `"C:\Users\me\Projects\myProject\"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Linq addict like me, you may enjoy this. Works regardless of the termination of the path string.

```
public static class PathExtensions
{
    public static string GetLastPathSegment(this string path)
    {
        string lastPathSegment = path
            .Split(new string[] {@"\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .LastOrDefault();

        return lastPathSegment;
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
lastSegment = Paths.GetLastPathSegment(@"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc");
lastSegment = Paths.GetLastPathSegment(@"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\");
```

Output:
    etc

Comment: Maybe consider using 'Path.DirectorySeparatorChar' instead of "\"

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is

```
dirName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
```