# How do I get the folder for the currently open file in c#

Tags: c#, directory

I am writing a wizard that pulls information from a database like file. This wizard doesn't get compiled, it just runs on command. I am not sure the correct term for that.

The issue is, I need to enter more information which will manipulate the database, and I want to store the values into a csv file that I use to manipulate the database.

So the question is: How do I get the folder for the currently open file in a c# application so that I can save a csv file to that folder?

edit: The path needs to be dynamic. Each database file is stored in a separate folder. I need the wizard to save to which ever folder I just opened the file from.

edit2 :
I am not opening the file programmatically. The file is being open by the user in the application. So, the user opens a file, and a bunch of database information is displayed. He then runs a wizard on that data where he can enter some coefficients, etc .. and that will change the information in the database file. I need to be able to store the coefficients he enters into the folder that contains the database file that he opened. I cannot access / change the application code, only the wizard code.

Thanks

Comment: 1. this is c# not python, 2. I need the application to supply the filename or current folder, it needs to be dynamic, not hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    var file = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Test.txt";
    var fileLocation = file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf("\\"));
```

Comment: The path needs to be dynamic. Each database file is stored in a separate folder. I need the wizard to save to which ever folder I just opened the file from.

Comment: Literally what I just told you. The path of the file will be there so just trim it down ffs.

Comment: I need to find the path of the currently open file dynamically. Each file is in a different folder. If I hardcode a file var .. that does me no good. I need the csv stored with the specific database file, each in a separate folder.

Comment: You're making my brain hurt. If you're opening a file in a C# program, store the location as a variable, since your app clearly knows where it is somehow and then just trim it down? I cannot explain this any other way unless you tell me step my step what you're talking about.

Comment: I am not opening the file programmatically. The file is being open by the user in the application. So, the user opens a file, and a bunch of database information is displayed. He then runs a wizard on that data where he can enter some coefficients, etc .. and that will change the information in the database file. I need to be able to store the coefficients he enters into the folder that contains the database file that he opened. I cannot access / change the application code, only the wizard code.

Comment: So, trigger an event after he opens the file which does exactly what I just told you?

Comment: I cant change the application code and the wizard is not run until after the database file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string directoryName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

I found this solution in this thread

[Get the (last part of) current directory name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018293/get-the-last-part-of-current-directory-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thanks, but again, I don't have a path or file or filename. I need the application to tell me the path of the file it currently has open. Reading through that post you linked I only see Environment.CurrentDirectory. I need something like that, but .. for some reason I cannot access Environment.CurrentDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Or where ever the database returns the file is stored
var filename = "C:\\Temp\\File\\Test.txt";          
var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
```

Should return C:\Temp\File

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DirectoryInfo` to get information about any directory:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            if (di != null)
            {
                FileInfo[] subFiles = di.GetFiles();
                if (subFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Files:");
                    foreach (FileInfo subFile in subFiles)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("   " + subFile.Name + " (" + subFile.Length + " bytes) " + "Directory name: " 
                            + di.Name + " Directory full name: " + di.FullName);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems like the right direction .. but gives me C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\CSSCRIPT\Cache\537240694 .. which looks like the location of the wizard? Is executing the wizard replacing the information about opening the file or .. am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: The executing wizard is caching the opened files to the `%temp%`.